# How to add new input field with .keyup()?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I have created add button to create input field. Let me show you my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var scntDiv = $('#add_words');
    var wordscount = 1 ;
    var i = $('.line').size() + 1; 
    $('#add').click(function() { 
      wordscount++;
      $('<div class="line">Word is ' + wordscount + '<input type="text" class="input' + wordscount + '" value="' + wordscount + '" /></div>').appendTo(scntDiv); 
      i++; 
      return false;
    });

<a id="add">Add</a>
<div id="add_words">
    <div class="line">Word is 1<input type="text" value="1" /></div>
</div>
```

I would like to use `.keyup()` function instead of `<a id="add">Add</a>`. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this below, [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) is a list of key codes

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (key === 32) {
        $('body').append('<p>stop touching your keyboard</p>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried keyup yet? It's as simple as assigning the keyup event to the input field instead of using the click event on the div.

The problem I see you'll run into is for every character, on keyup, a new input field will be created, so you'll be able to solve that with one of two ways: 1) Remove the keyup event once a new input field has been created, in which case, from what little information you gave, I'm assuming you would want to assign the keyup event to the new input field so if somebody starts typing in there, another input field is created.

(You'll need jquery's [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind) and [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind) methods)

Or 2) create a flag that says if there's a new field or not. This option is a bit less optimized and the problem that I have with going this route is the event fires for every character that's added to the input field, but I'm just throwing it out there in case you need it, since there's not much detail on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I haven't tried yet, 
I'm new in JQuery. 
I would like create an on line dictionary. using 'keyup()' add extra text field for customers to add new words to database